# prestashop logo rollover issue

Tags: prestashop, rollover, graphical-logo

this is my first time working with prestashop just to put that out there. Ive been playing around for a few days changing certain things for my theme but one thing remains to elude me that I cant figure out and that is how to make the logo a rollover image. Ive tried working in the header.tpl file as well as the global.css file, If anyone can help me out in figure out how to make a rollover work that would be much appreciated.

Comment: here is the link to the page so you can see whats happening http://artbymymindseye.com/theshop/index.php?

Answer (score 0):

Just add in the global.css:

```
#header_logo:hover{

}
```

Comment: Ive tried this, the result im getting is part of the image showing up underneath the logo shown, and no way to move it up.

Comment: http://artbymymindseye.com/theshop/index.php? here is the link to the page so you can see what im talkin about.